# X-Cluster download failed response when running curl_exec PHP

Tags: php

I have this code implemented inside Laravel.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$link = "https://link";
$token = "";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer {$token}",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($curl, $header) use (&$responseHeaders) {
    $len = strlen($header);
    $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
    if (count($header) < 2)
        return $len;
    $responseHeaders[strtolower(trim($header[0]))][] = trim($header[1]);
    return $len;
});

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err      = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

It takes time to download `https://link` and then I got a `$response` value of

```
{
    "Message": "X-Cluster download failed",
    "Exception": null
}
```

From the return message I have no Idea what is

```
X-Cluster download failed
```

means.

I take to research but couldn't find a direct answer.

Any Idea?

Edit: https://link is valid link that represented tha original one it's a sensitive and private, the reason why I pasted like that.

Comment: Is "https://link"; a valid link?

Comment: Yes that is very valid and sensitive link the reason why I pasted it like that

Comment: This message is from the service itself, isn't it?  I mean, you'd get the same message if you weren't using CURL but some other mechanism like your browser to do the GET.  You'll need to ask the service provider what the message means.